# 複数のタグを指定してスクレイピング

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

あるurlのソースコードから、下記の2箇所を取得したいのですが、
結果のリストが空になってしまいます。

```py
def get_all_reviews(url):
    rvw_list_text = []

    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='lxml')

    for r in soup.find_all(['dd','p']):
        if r.name == 'dd' and r.get('class') == 'rpoint-tx-point':
            rvw_list_text.append(r.get_text(strip=True))
        elif r.name == 'p' and r.get('class') == 'review-tit-article':
            rvw_list_text.append(r.get_text(strip=True))
        print(rvw_list_text)

url = "https://www.xxxxx"
rvw_list_text = get_all_reviews(url)

reviews_text = []
for i in range(len(rvw_list_text)):
    if key_word in rvw_list_text[i].text:    # 検索ワードが含まれていたら
        rvw_text = textwrap.fill(rvw_list_text[i].text, 80)
        reviews_text.append(rvw_text)
```

取得したい箇所：

```html
<dd class="rpoint-tx-point">4.50点</dd>
<p class="review-tx-article">
<span class="review-tit-article">カリキュラム</span>5教科が習えるのはいいのですが、部活をやっているので、土曜日に部活の後に3時間半の授業はちょっと長くてキツイ日もあるかなと思います。</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

可能性1: コンテンツ表示のためにページ内でjavascriptが使われている。
可能性2: bs4で要素のclassを取得する際に、配列として渡される。

2つの可能性を考慮して、seleniumを使って書き換えました。

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

def get_all_reviews(url):
    rvw_list_text = []
    driver.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="html.parser")

    for r in soup.find_all(['dd', 'p']):
        try:
            n_cls = r["class"]
            print(n_cls)
        except KeyError:
            continue
        if 'rpoint-tx-point' in n_cls:
            rvw_list_text.append(r.get_text(strip=True))
        elif 'review-tx-article' in n_cls:
            rvw_list_text.append(r.get_text(strip=True))

    return rvw_list_text


url = "http://xxx"
rvw_list_text = get_all_reviews(url)

print(rvw_list_text)
```

seleniumでchrome使うためには、chromeをインストールした上で、chromeバージョンに対応したchromedriverをPATHに通す必要があります。
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home